# Canvas c =surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(rect) ;c.drawColor(color) ; the rect will be redrawed

Tags: android, android-canvas

```
Canvas c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(rect) ;
c.drawColor(color) ;
```

The previous rect will be redrawn by the color. I want to retain the previous rect, but can't remove `c.drawColor(color)`, what should I do ?

Comment: rect? what rect? you dont use any `c.drawRect()`... what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: i am not use any c.drawRect()  i am a chinese  my English is pool

Comment: `"the previous rect will be redrawed by the color"` so what rect do you mean if tou are not using `drawRect`?

Comment: i just want to remain the pervious rect whic have some other lines,but when i use c.drawColor(red);c.drawPath(newPath,paint) , the pervious rect will be clean and full of the red ,so how can i remain the rect contains some line and add newPath.